# JOOQ How to produce unique list when joining multiple tables

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have three tables: `SchoolTable`, `SchoolOrgTable`, and `SchoolDetailsTable`. The relationships between these tables are as follows:

- `SchoolTable` to `SchoolOrgTable` is a one-to-many relationship.
- `SchoolOrgTable` to `SchoolDetailsTable` is a many-to-one relationship.

I'm currently retrieving data from these tables using a JOOQ query like this:

```java
SelectJoinStep<Record> result = dsl.select()
    .from(SchoolTable)
    .join(SchoolOrgTable)
    .on(SchoolTable.A_ID.eq(SchoolOrgTable.ATest_ID))
    .leftJoin(SchoolOrgTable)
    .on(SchoolTable.A_ID.eq(SchoolOrgTable.B_Id))
    .leftJoin(SchoolDetailsTable)
    .on(SchoolDetailsTable.C_ID.eq(SchoolOrgTable.B_ID));
```

However, the result I'm getting is duplicating the `schoolId` for each associated `SchoolDetails`. Here's an example of what I'm currently getting:

```json
[
  {
    "schoolId": 1,
    "schoolName": "JaySchool",
    "isActive": true,
    "SchoolDetails": [
      {
        "detailsID": 1,
        "detailsName": "Test",
        "details": "schoolIsGood"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "schoolId": 1,
    "schoolName": "JaySchool",
    "isActive": true,
    "SchoolDetails": [
      {
        "detailsID": 2,
        "detailsName": "Test1",
        "details": "awesome"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "schoolId": 2,
    "schoolName": "TermSchool",
    "isActive": true,
    "SchoolDetails": [
      {
        "detailsID": 3,
        "detailsName": "Test",
        "details": "Nice"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want the result to be structured like this, with each schoolId associated with its SchoolDetails:
Note: I should be able to groupBy schoolName,detailsName

```json
[
  {
    "schoolId": 1,
    "schoolName": "JaySchool",
    "isActive": true,
    "SchoolDetails": [
      {
        "detailsID": 1,
        "detailsName": "Test",
        "details": "schoolIsGood"
      },
      {
        "detailsID": 2,
        "detailsName": "Test1",
        "details": "awesome"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "schoolId": 2,
    "schoolName": "TermSchool",
    "isActive": true,
    "SchoolDetails": [
      {
        "detailsID": 3,
        "detailsName": "test3",
        "details": "Nice"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: this ''join(SchoolOrgTable) .on(SchoolTable.A_ID.eq(SchoolOrgTable.ATest_ID))'' seems excessively

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to get nested JSON documents is by using jOOQ's SQL/JSON support, e.g. [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/json-arrayagg-function/). For example:

```java
dsl.select(jsonObject(
        key("schoolId").value(SCHOOL.ID),
        key("schoolName").value(SCHOOL.NAME),
        key("isActive").value(SCHOOL.ACTIVE),
        key("SchoolDetails").value(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
            key("detailsID").value(SCHOOL_DETAILS.ID),
            key("detailsName").value(SCHOOL_DETAILS.NAME),
            key("details").value(SCHOOL_DETAILS.DETAILS)
        )).orderBy(SCHOOL_DETAILS.NAME))
    ))
    .from(SCHOOL)
    .leftJoin(SCHOOL_DETAILS)
    .on(SCHOOL_DETAILS.SCHOOL_ID.eq(SCHOOL.ID))
    .groupBy(SCHOOL.ID) // Assuming there's a primary key here
    .orderBy(SCHOOL.NAME, SCHOOL.ACTIVE)
    .fetch();
```

Comment: the problem with this is I need to orderBy SchoolName,IsActive,detailsName if I groupBy detailsName this will break the the unique list, is there anyway I can try this?

Comment: @EveryDayLearner: The `SCHOOL` columns can be ordered on the top level query, the `SCHOOL_DETAILS` columns can be ordered on the `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` function, see my updated answer

Comment: awesome Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple ways to solve your issue

1. JSONObject (as in the other answer):

It's like native query

```
dsl.select(jsonObject(
        key("schoolId").value(SCHOOL.ID),
        key("schoolName").value(SCHOOL.NAME),
        key("isActive").value(SCHOOL.ACTIVE),
        key("SchoolDetails").value(jsonArrayAgg(jsonObject(
            key("detailsID").value(SCHOOL_DETAILS.ID),
            key("detailsName").value(SCHOOL_DETAILS.NAME),
            key("details").value(SCHOOL_DETAILS.DETAILS)
        )).orderBy(SCHOOL_DETAILS.NAME))
    ))
    .from(SCHOOL)
    .leftJoin(SCHOOL_DETAILS)
    .on(SCHOOL_DETAILS.SCHOOL_ID.eq(SCHOOL.ID))
    .groupBy(SCHOOL.ID) // Assuming there's a primary key here
    .orderBy(SCHOOL.NAME, SCHOOL.ACTIVE)
    .fetch();
```

2. multisetAgg:

Docs: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/aggregate-functions/multiset-agg-function/

multisetAgg operates on the same principle as directly specifying JSONObject (from first option), but you don't have to prescribe everything explicitly

In this situation, this option is unlikely to work, but I am obliged to mention it. When executing the code, there will most likely be an incorrect alias binding. Perhaps this has been fixed in new versions

```
dsl.select(
        SCHOOL.ID.as("schoolId"),
        SCHOOL.NAME.as("schoolName"),
        SCHOOL.ACTIVE.as("isActive"),
        multisetAgg( // aliases inside multisetAgg may not work
            SCHOOL_DETAILS.ID.as("detailsID"),
            SCHOOL_DETAILS.NAME.as("detailsName"),
            SCHOOL_DETAILS.DETAILS.as("details")
        ).orderBy(SCHOOL_DETAILS.NAME)).as("SchoolDetails")
    )
    .from(SCHOOL)
    .leftJoin(SCHOOL_DETAILS).on(SCHOOL_DETAILS.SCHOOL_ID.eq(SCHOOL.ID))
    .groupBy(SCHOOL.ID, SCHOOL.NAME, SCHOOL.ACTIVE)
    .orderBy(SCHOOL.NAME, SCHOOL.ACTIVE)
    .fetch();
```

3. multiset:

Docs: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/multiset-value-constructor/

Just like multisetAgg, multiset operates on the same principle as directly specifying JSONObject (from first option), but you don't have to prescribe everything explicitly

Briefly about multiset: a subquery is used inside the construction, which can refer to one or more values from an external query. In this case, the internal request refers to SCHOOL.ID for filtering values. This option is the most flexible

```
dsl.select(
        SCHOOL.ID.as("schoolId"),
        SCHOOL.NAME.as("schoolName"),
        SCHOOL.ACTIVE.as("isActive"),
        multiset(
            dsl.select(
                SCHOOL_DETAILS.ID.as("detailsID"),
                SCHOOL_DETAILS.NAME.as("detailsName"),
                SCHOOL_DETAILS.DETAILS.as("details")
            )
                .from(SCHOOL_DETAILS)
                .where(SCHOOL_DETAILS.SCHOOL_ID.eq(SCHOOL.ID))
                .orderBy(SCHOOL_DETAILS.NAME)
        ).as("SchoolDetails")
    )
    .from(SCHOOL)
    .groupBy(SCHOOL.ID, SCHOOL.NAME, SCHOOL.ACTIVE)
    .orderBy(SCHOOL.NAME, SCHOOL.ACTIVE)
    .fetch();
```